# Unable to use printf() outside of main, unless printf() is used at least once in main

Tags: c, debugging, printing, runtime-error, stm32

I am debugging faulty serial connection on TrueSTM Atollic IDE.

Watch window, `Expressions` requires me to select a variable and display it as an array. Drawback is that I need to reselect that on each recompile, it gets very slow for +100 values and it doesn't look very clear to me.

So I have created function which simply prints out the bytes held in one of the buffers, those are then displayed to me over to SWV Console.

`freertos.c`

```
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

uint8_t X [4] = {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
uint8_t * xt = X;

 osThreadDef(CAN_Producer, FrameExtractorNEW, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
 defaultTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(CAN_Producer), NULL);

void FrameExtractorNEW(void const * argument){

            Print_Bytes(xt,4);  // fails
            printf("Cheese\n")  // fails
}
```

`main.c`

```
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "can.h"
#include "dma.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_CAN2_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();

  MX_FREERTOS_Init();
  osKernelStart();      
  while (1)
  {}
}


// accept pointer to first element, and number of consecutive byte values to display
void Print_Bytes(uint8_t * a1, int bytes_to_read){  
    for (int i = 0; i<bytes_to_read; i++){
        printf("0x%02X " , *(a1+i));        
    }   
}
```

Easy and straight forward stuff so far, or so it seems.

My problem is that if I try to use the function `Print_Bytes()` in the `freertos.c` it will work, but only provided that it has been invoked at least once prior in `main.c`. Printing out anything using `printf()` in `main.c` at least once will also make it work elsewhere in other files.

Without that 'enabling' program execution goes to `HardFault_Handler()` with following faults.

[image]

I have necessary includes for `printf()` and `Print_Bytes()` for the functions that call them but it doesn't seem to be enough to get it to work as I expect it should work.

Comment: You're probably invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) elsewhere in your program.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that others can run that should reproduce the problem.

Comment: My guess is that you don't pass a valid pointer to the function. Probably uninitialized.

Comment: Also note that for any pointer *or array* `a` and index `i`, the expression `*(a + i)` is *exactly* equal to `a[i]`. The latter is usually easier to read and understand. And a couple of characters less to write.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude I've sidestepped into that line pointers aren't an issue, I can not use printf() with a constant char regardless.

Comment: It's not about `printf` but about some memory access violation. Given the abort is imprecise (asynchronous) I would say it might have happened *much* before your `printf`s are called.

Comment: @Eugene As you can see, people are guessing. Unless OP updates his question, no body will be able to answer.

Comment: You have written a few questions, and been a member for a few years. Even if not very active as a poster, you should still know better than to post a question like this. Please take a refresher of [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also please re-read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: A couple of points: You don't need the variable `xt`, you can use `X` directly everywhere you need a pointer to its first element. Secondly, could it be an initialization problem? Have the initialized data segment been copied to the right place? Or the file streams needed for `printf` to work, is `stdout` initialized and can be written to?

Comment: The code you present for function `FrameExtractorNEW()` contains so-called "smart quotes" where ordinary ASCII double quotes are required.  If this comes from retyping your code, then don't -- cut & paste your code into the question instead.  If the smart quotes are actually present in the real code, then fix that first.

Comment: Maybe it's not allowed to call `printf()` from a thread in FreeRTOS ?

Comment: BTW, I don't think the code that create the thread can compile outside of a function.

Comment: Yeah, the `osThreadCreate` line looks misplaced.

Comment: The quotes on `“Cheese\n”` are incorrect.

Comment: I sort of wish I skipped the array aspect and the background. It's the printf() statement alone from my deduction. If I include the rest of the code I can display serial bytes to the console as expected but only if printf() gets invoked at least once in the main.c. If printf() is not used at all in main.c then any use of printf() outside of main.c will crash the execution.

Comment: @Eugene Sh you may be right about osThreadCreate being misplaced, I used the template from keil website. It does work in spawning a thread though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `much before your printfs are called` not much more. Usually up to ABH clock *2 before. So 3-4 machine code instruction. It is related to the bus propagation times.

Comment: @mega_creamery if you post the image - post the rest of it ass well as it contains the most interesting information

Answer (score 1):

I bet that the `printf` on the first run initializes some internal variables. In the main it uses the main program heap and the stack. If you use for the first time in the task it does it on the task heap and stack and none of the standard allocations may do not work in this context (printf uses the malloc function).

Personally I have written my own freeRTOS safe versions of this family of functions. It is very bad practice to use thread unsafe functions in the multi thread environment.

Answer (score 0):

likely your minimal heap size is not big enough  (ld file ide option ...)
default lib (nano etc ..) will call sbrake"  to split stack en enlarge heap but it is nto mean to be used in rtos context so it wan't work if the stack pointer is not the main stack :(

So if you do a first print or malloc etc ...inside main before oskernel start it will help (sp is main stack)  by enlarging your heap . 
If you do it first time in a thread it wan't succeed cos "sp" use by sbrake  is freertos task memory not the "main stack"  thus printf fail to alloc mem

You may notice that  printf  rely or std lib malloc that is not re-entrant nor multi thread safe ... a safer formated  print can be done via vsnprintf  formating string to a task owned buffer.